# fail2ban performance considerations regarding log size, complexity, and finditme settings

Tags: python, performance, cpu-usage, ram, fail2ban

I'm new to fail2ban and having a hard time figuring out performance considerations for different configurations I'm thinking about setting up. This is running on a raspberry pi board, so performance is a concern.

The obvious optimizations I can think of are using efficient regular expressions and only the minimum number of jails needed. I guess my specific questions are:

1. How does resource usage increase with respect to findtime values? I'm guessing very small and very large values could both impact the server in different ways regarding RAM vs. CPU.
2. Similarly, how does the size of a log file and the number of different log files monitored by fail2ban impact overall resource usage?

As an example, this jail would let someone try 3,600 SSH login passwords a day if they figured out the fail2ban config and adjusted their script timing to accommodate.

```
[ssh]
enabled  = true
action   = iptables-allports[name=ssh]
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6
findtime = 120
```

If we changed findtime to a different extreme of 86400 (1 day), it would only allow 5 attempts a day, but now it's monitoring a larger portion of the log file. How does this affect resource usage?

Another example, a jail for POST flood attacks:

```
[apache-post-flood]
enabled  = true
action   = iptables-allports[name=apache-post-flood]
filter   = apache-post-flood
logpath  = /var/log/apache2/*access.log
maxretry = 10
findtime = 10
```

Here, we have the opposite, where the findtime counter is resetting every 10 seconds. It's also monitoring all *access logs (I'm guessing, again, I'm new to this). That could mean it's monitoring access.log, other_vhosts_access.log, and perhaps an https_access.log for https portions of the site. What if it's been a busy day and these files are all 10-20mb each?

Hope this helps explain what's on my mind. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to find out this, test it, nothing else.

Add monitoring regarding memory usage if needed, but there is no formula that would tell you the amount of CPU, IO or memory that you will need.

As a general rule, when you retune your system, put in a comment the new value and the date when you needed to retune it. This will allow you to see if there is any trend.

My personal take is to increase the affected resource with 30-50% each time. If you use less than this you are risking on doing it too often.